# Using SneakyInput - Does not have self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to implement the SneakyInput into my Cocos2D and Box2D game and I get errors in the SneakyJoystick and SneakyButton files where:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

causes an error, and these classes inherit CCNode.

Can anyone help please?

### UPDATE

Error says:

```
SneakyJoystick.m:56:14: Property 'userInteractionEnabled' not found on object of type 'SneakyJoystick *'


SneakyJoystick.m:57:14: Property 'multipleTouchEnabled' not found on object of type 'SneakyJoystick *'
```

Comment: Which version of SneakyInput? Only v0.4 upwards works with cocos2d v3. Also post the exact error messages, "causes an error" is not enough detail.

Comment: The version is 4.0 sneaky input but I'm using cocos2d and box2d v2.x